# Network speed horribly slow only between two specific nodes

Tags: networking, ping, latency

I have a VPN in which (mainly two) clients communicate with each other. I realized that the throughput between two of the clients is extremely low (**(2) -> (1)** in the picture below) in one direction and later found out that this problem also occurs without a VPN (direct connection between two routers attached to the internet).

The following picture should help understanding my infrastructure:

[image: Network speeds]

where *Ref* is a reference to determine the maximum speed for each node (that where two speed test providers in my case).

**(1)** is a Raspberry Pi using latest Raspbian.

The throughput of the Raspberry Pi **(1)** is about 20 MBit/s in local network in either direction (wireless).

Throughput of **(2)** is also fine from any computer on the internet in any direction.

The combination described in the picture is the only combination known to me in which the bottleneck appears.

Latency is really stable between both nodes but I realized when pinging from **(1)** to **(2)** that `icmp_seq` sometimes increases by more than one. Is that an indicator for packet loss?

```
PING 192.168.4.1 (192.168.4.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.4.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=58.10 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.4.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=128 time=48.8 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.4.1: icmp_seq=6 ttl=128 time=71.5 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.4.1: icmp_seq=7 ttl=128 time=66.3 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.4.1: icmp_seq=9 ttl=128 time=58.4 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.4.1: icmp_seq=12 ttl=128 time=53.9 ms
```

Please let me know which information you need - for now, I have no idea where else to search for the problem.

Comment: What loss stats does 'ping' show once stopped? Are both (1) and (2) on the same ISP? If not, how does the direct path from one to another (traceroute) compare to paths taken to (ref)?

Comment: Indeed - I got an average packet loss of around 35%. ISPs differ on both nodes.

traceroute reveals that the route to (ref) uses three hops while the route to (2) uses six hops. But that can't result in a performance difference, right? When packets arrive, they arrive with very low latency...

Comment: What I forgot to mention is that the problem occurs sporadically. In the first weeks, everything worked fine. But in the last weeks the problem occured more and more often. Maybee a result of COVID-19 quarantine? That would be the most simple solution but that really does not seem to be likely to me as other routes are unaffected.

Comment: No, it's actually very likely **because** they're different routes.

Comment: Is there a way to find out which hop is dropping the packets?

Comment: traceroute from (1) to (2) yields:

`traceroute to XXX, 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 | 1  speedport.ip (192.168.2.1)  22.847 ms  22.735 ms  22.714 ms
 | 2  * * *
 | 3  * * *
 | 4  xxx  42.396 ms  42.698 ms 195.145.92.1 (195.145.92.1)  45.214 ms
 | 5  xxx  46.627 ms  49.432 ms  50.584 ms
 | 6  xxx 58.422 ms  41.967 ms  43.302 ms
 | 7  * * xxx  42.429 ms
 | 8  xxx  41.086 ms  39.831 ms  41.981 ms
 | 9  xxx  91.460 ms *  84.392 ms
| 10  * * *
| 11  * * *
| 12  * * *`

Note that "|" means a new line. There is no huge difference in comparison to routes that work as expected...